# Why am I getting a 'connection closed' error when using NextJS 13.4's streaming feature with React Suspense?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13, react-suspense

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/az5gL.png)

THE ABOVE ERROR OCCURS when I tried to load more than two data with suspense (streaming). I'm using Next JS 13.4 with App router by the way.

```js
export const serverApi = async <T>(
  url: string,
  init?: RequestInit
): Promise<T> => {
  const response = await fetch(BASE_URL.API + url, init);
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(response.statusText);
  }
  return await (response.json() as Promise<T>);
};
```

```js
export const getArticles = async () => {
  return await serverApi<Article[]>(API.ARTICLES, {
    cache: "no-store",
  });
};

export const getArticle = async (id: string) => {
  return await serverApi<Article>(API.ARTICLE_WITH_ID(id), {
    cache: "no-store",
  });
};
```

```js
const Header = async () => {
  return (
    <header className="relative w-full flex items-center justify-center">
      <div />
      <HeaderNavigation />
      <Suspense fallback={<HeaderProfileSpinner />}>
        {/* @ts-ignore */}
        <HeaderProfile />
      </Suspense>
    </header>
  );
};

const HeaderProfile = async () => {
  const cookie = getCookie();
  const queryClient = getQueryClient();

  await queryClient.prefetchQuery(USER_QUERY_KEYS.me(), () =>
    getUserMe(cookie)
  );

  const dehydratedState = dehydrate(queryClient);

  return (
    <Hydrate state={dehydratedState}>
      <HeaderProfileImage />
    </Hydrate>
  );
};
```

I use API like this. I'm using Page Router for API.
For more details, I use Prisma for ORM, Postgres (Supabase) for DB, and use Vercel deployment.
I think 'connection closed' means that the server aborts the connection when one of the streaming has resolved, and it wasn't like I expected. I thought the whole point of streaming is rendering multiple contents in parallel but it didn't work. It's kinda weird that the error doesn't happen in localhost.

Comment: Hi, the use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Please edit your question. Thank you

Comment: This issue is most likely timeouts from your backend. If something takes more than 12-15s+ fetch, then Next will throw a Connection Closed error. The only way I was able to fix it was to make the response faster (under 10s). It appears to be fixed in Next v13.4.4-canary.10+ according to this issue on Github: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49205

Comment: @Dev-Siri Thanks for reply. The connection error happens less than 3 seconds loading the page so it is not the case. I tried Next v13.4.4-canary.11 but it won't work either. I think I have to wait to get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly related to streaming but anyone dealing with this **connection closed** error, my site was working fine until randomly it would crash after 5-10 seconds with this error as well. It worked just fine on my local environment but my deployed site on Vercel was not.

I tried a bunch of things and nothing was working until I simply upgraded my next from **v13.3 to v13.4.12** and it fixed the problem. If you're dealing with the same issue I'd recommend trying to upgrade/downgrade from your current version first and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not about `Suspense`, but I faced with this error, and resolved by upgrading Next to latest.

Also in my window I've recieved this:
[image]

Maybe this will help someone in future.

```
yarn upgrade next
```

or

```
yarn add next@latest
```

Comment: I faced this issue and upgrading to the latest version (13.5.3) doesn't help. Also tried to downgrade to several versions, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: yep, the same thing... 
it's gone after updrade, but after several time it started again

Comment: I see, thank you.

Comment: I made several redeploy now but the error still exists. Have no idea now how to fix this.

Comment: there was some variants with widing memory size of nodejs, but did'nt try yet

Comment: I fixed the problem, actually its not about nextjs version or anything, the error happened on the blogs page where I fetch a list of blogs in the server component and each blog has a very long string content, and the error occurred when the whole list was passed to the client component, reducing number of blogs fetched each time fixed the issue. This error only happened when deployed to Vercel.